# Request for more experienced eyes to check for x-frame-options

Tags: iframe, head, x-frame-options, connection-refused

I'm trying to create an iframe to https://www.wirral.gov.uk/health-and-social-care/health-wirral/coronavirus-update but I get the dreaded Refused to Connect message.

After some research, I assume it is because that website is preventing other sites from embedding it, but I can't actually find the x-frame setting in the head of this website...  It's the first time I've looked for such a thing so I might not be looking in the right place, but could someone be so kind as to have a look at this site and see if it is actually stopping my iframe from loading, in case it's something else I need to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Framing is blocked due to X-Frame-Options. Open developer tools (F12) and reload the page to see the requests on the Network tab. Find the main page load and look at the response headers:
[image]